# How to find column with matching value and assign it to the textbox1 in user form VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell, userform

i am having problem loading data from matched cell to current date into the texbox in the user form

I have

```
Private Sub NSheet_Click()
    MoveSheet (1)
    txtBox2.Text = "1st: " & " 2nd: " & " 3rd: "
End Sub
```

and when next is selected moveSheet will switch to the next sheet in the workbook
then i have function

```
Sub FindtheDay()
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim kolona As Long
    Dim today As Date
    today = Date

    With ActiveSheet.Range("F2:AJ2")
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=today, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            kolona = CStr(rFind.Column)
            KolLN = kolona
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

that is looking for cell that match to the current date (date only)

then i need that column number as reference to the cell that is 48 row below the one where it was found.

basicli, when Next button is pressed i whant it to switch sheet and then to find column with matching date and then to point to cell Range(ColumNumber & "50") and send that value into textbox

- also i have three cels ColumnNumber,50,51 and 52 that i whant to put in textbox on user form

All I have tried is giving me error about wrong type

Also I am using public variables because some of them i need i other Sub procedures

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you cant create a Range of Columns like that. It has to be like this:

```
.Range(Columns(1), Columns(50))
```

If you want to show some value in a userform then you can assign it with addressing it like that.

```
Sub Test() 
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not working, still getting error about type mismatch.The Form stays open all the time while cycling through  the worksheets with Previous and Next buttons on the form. As soon I hit Next it will switch the worksheet and activate it. Then I need to find column reference that is pointing to the current day and return value from cell where it is going to be the same column but row will be 50, 51 and 52.

Comment: where does the type mismatch occure, i couldnt recreate it.